# MSSQL - Counting dates from two columns grouping by external date range

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple table containing case number (ID), opening_date and end_date where end_date have null values (unfinished cases). It looks like this:

```
ID  opening_date    end_date 
1   2021-01-04      2021-01-14
2   2021-01-04      2021-01-26
3   2021-01-14      2021-02-15
4   2021-02-01      NULL
5   2021-02-04      2021-02-26
6   2021-02-10      2021-02-15
```

I'm trying to write a select query which will show me simply by month/week or day (nevermind), how many cases were set up (opening_date) and how many were closed (end_date) per each month./week. The problem is that I cannot use opening or end date in filters because not every date from opening_date column is in end_date and vice versa. It should be **specific date range generated separately as external table** in first column or something like that, so if there's situation, where neither opening nor end date occurs (in a day/week/month), a row with zeros should be shown as in the first date below - The result of example by day:

```
date    openings    endings
2021-01-01  0   0
2021-01-02  0   0
2021-01-03  0   0
2021-01-04  2   0
2021-01-05  0   0
2021-01-06  0   0
2021-01-07  0   0
2021-01-08  0   0
2021-01-09  0   0
2021-01-10  0   0
2021-01-11  0   0
2021-01-12  0   0
2021-01-13  0   0
2021-01-14  1   1
2021-01-15  0   0
2021-01-16  0   0
2021-01-17  0   0
2021-01-18  0   0
2021-01-19  0   0
2021-01-20  0   0
2021-01-21  0   0
2021-01-22  0   0
2021-01-23  0   0
2021-01-24  0   0
2021-01-25  0   0
2021-01-26  0   1
2021-01-27  0   0
2021-01-28  0   0
2021-01-29  0   0
2021-01-30  0   0
2021-01-31  0   0
2021-02-01  1   0
2021-02-02  0   0
2021-02-03  0   0
2021-02-04  1   0
2021-02-05  0   0
2021-02-06  0   0
2021-02-07  0   0
2021-02-08  0   0
2021-02-09  0   0
2021-02-10  1   0
2021-02-11  0   0
2021-02-12  0   0
2021-02-13  0   0
2021-02-14  0   0
2021-02-15  0   2
2021-02-16  0   0
2021-02-17  0   0
2021-02-18  0   0
2021-02-19  0   0
2021-02-20  0   0
2021-02-21  0   0
2021-02-22  0   0
2021-02-23  0   0
2021-02-24  0   0
2021-02-25  0   0
2021-02-26  0   1
2021-02-27  0   0
2021-02-28  0   0
```

By months:

```
Month   openings endings
2021-01    3       2
2021-02    3       3
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you just need a `SUM` here.

Comment: I know, exactly SUM CASE, but I wonder how to take dates (all dates in the calendar) which not occurs in both columns and use the range in this select. Here is the problem.

Comment: Why do you need a `CASE`? The `SUM` of 28 `0`'s, a `2` and a `1` is `3`; which is the result you want. I don't see why `SUM(openings)` doesn't work.

Comment: @DARIUS, a calendar table with all dates of interest will allow you to use that for the date range, with a left join for the counts. Search for "calendar table" and you'll find many solutions to create one. You could also use a CTE to create the dates on the fly but it won't generally perform as well as a table with materialized dates.

Comment: You are right but how to force MSSQL to show all dates in select, not only occured in this two columns? Do I have to declare a date range and use it somewhere as subselect?

Comment: Dan Guzman, After Your comment, there will be finally a simple, but less efficent solution. I will create (VB.NET) a datatable containing all dates, in the next step I'll make 2 selects of two columns in DB and fill them my DT using "FOR" loop. I see no other way out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need a calendar table for this.** You start with the calendar, and `LEFT JOIN` everything else.

To get the calculation for each day, we can unpivot and group, then count daily totals

You can have a real table. Or you can [generate it on the fly](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1), like this:

```
WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT c = 1
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
    L1 AS ( SELECT c = 1 FROM L0 A, L0 B, L0 C ),
    Nums AS ( SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
              FROM L1 ),
    Dates AS ( SELECT [date] = DATEADD(day, rownum, '20180101')
              FROM Nums )

SELECT
    d.[date],
    openings = ISNULL(t.openings, 0),
    endings  = ISNULL(t.endings, 0)
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT v.AllDates,
           openings = COUNT(IsOpen),
           endings  = COUNT(IsEnd)
    FROM YourTable t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        (opening_date, 1, NULL),
        (end_date,  NULL,    1)
    ) v(AllDates, IsOpen, IsEnd)
    GROUP BY v.AllDates
) t ON t.AllDates = d.[date];
```