# Can I return a NULL if the row which I am trying to query does not exist?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which pulls values in a column in a defined date range (last 10 yrs). If data in that column is missing for any specific date, the row simply does not exist in the table.

Is there a way that I can return NULLs if there is no row? Basically, I still want to return all dates in the range, but if a row does not exist, then I would just return a NULL for that specific date.

Comment: A date/calendar table would help with this. Load a separate table with all dates in the range you are after and then LEFT JOIN from that table to your table you are querying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSSQL - Counting dates from two columns grouping by external date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68454443/mssql-counting-dates-from-two-columns-grouping-by-external-date-range) Not exactly the same, because here you don't want to group, but the principle is the same: use a calendar table

Answer (score 0):

The below will give you a listing of all dates between two dates.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20110913',
        @MaxDate DATE = '20210913';

SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, 
@MinDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;
```

Use this table to join to your table by date and any dates that are missing will show as null.

Comment: I've thought about creating a table to join my table with, but maybe my original question needs to be modified. The real scenario is that my table has unique entity identifiers, each   needing to return nulls in that specified date range. However, one unique entity ID could have a row for 20210831, while another unique ID might not have that row. I would need the query to return the data that exists for one entity, and null for the entity ID for which the row does not exist. Does your solution still stand?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to LEFT JOIN, in the example below the user is displayed even if they don't have an order. LEFT JOIN means keep the data on the left even if it doesn't have a match in the right table, if you used an INNER JOIN then it would only return rows that had data in both tables, hence would remove the NULL OrderId rows.

I notice you mentions date ranges (e.g dates table)too which could be the second part so this might help with that if you are going down that route, https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/08/date-tables-are-great-for-users-but-not-so-great-for-performance/

[image]

See full example below you can run, take note of the LEFT JOIN

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

    CREATE TABLE #Users (
        Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
        [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #Users ([Name] )
    VALUES('Andrew'),
    ('Bob'), 
    ('Dave'), 
    ('Philip')

    SELECT * FROM #Users

    CREATE TABLE #Orders (
        Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
        UserId INT NOT NULL,
        Cost DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Users FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES #Users (Id) 
    )

    INSERT INTO #Orders (UserId, Cost) 
    VALUES(1, 2.99),
    (1, 5.99), 
    (4, 8.99)

    SELECT * FROM #Orders

    SELECT U.Id AS UserId, U.[Name], O.Id AS OrderId FROM #Users AS U
    LEFT JOIN #Orders AS O ON O.UserId = U.Id

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Rolling back changes, there was an error!!' 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(MAX)  
    SELECT @Msg=ERROR_MESSAGE() 
    RAISERROR('Error Occured: %s', 20, 101,@msg) WITH LOG
END CATCH
```